# Convergence Theory

Tags: calculus, integration

Using convergence theory, show that 
$$\int_{0}^\infty  \left(\frac x{x^3 +1} \right) dx$$

is convergent.

I think it might be a typo since taking the integral to zero shows divergence in most cases.

Comment: Use ${x \over {1+x^3}} \sim {1 \over x^2}$ when $x \to \infty$

Comment: and on $[0,1]$ the integrand is bounded by $1$. Note that the singularity occurs in $-1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{x^3+1}$ and $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ for any $x\in \textbf{[} 1,+\infty\textbf{[}$.

For all $x\in \textbf{[} 1,+\infty\textbf{[}$ we have $0<\displaystyle f(x)\leq \frac{x}{x^3}=g(x)$.

Therefore, since both $f$ and $g$ are positive we have

$$\int _1^{+\infty}\frac{x}{x^3+1} \,dx\leq \int _1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \,dx$$

From the fact that $\displaystyle \int _1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \,dx$ converges and $f$ is positive follows that $\displaystyle \int _1^{+\infty}\frac{x}{x^3+1} \,dx$ also converges.

Now note that $f$ is bounded on $\textbf{[} 0,1\textbf{]}$, therefore $$\underbrace{\int _0^1f(x)\, dx}_{\displaystyle \in \Bbb R} +\int _1^{+\infty}f(x)=\int _0^{+\infty}\frac{x}{x^3+1} \,dx$$ converges.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Thanks.

Comment: sry i forgot to delete it, nevermind that, I got downvoted for mistakes long after correctic them